# How to utilize audience targeting with javascript?

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, audience-targeting, sharepoint-hosted-app

Im creating a SharePoint-hosted app (restricted to use client side code only), and I want to retrieve documents from a library. Each document have a Target audience field.

I want to, in javascript:

1. Read the Global audience from the list item
2. Detect if current user belongs to the Global audience.

Is this even possible? I have browsed the web a lot for this.

Answer (score 6):

No, audiences are not supported in the SharePoint client object model.  Its only supported in the Server Object Model.  In the past I created a Web Service in SharePoint that could take a user name and return the audiences for that user, leveraging the Server Object Model...but that approach probably doesn't work in your scenario.